# onBlur / onClick conflict with CodeMirror2 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, codemirror, onblur

I have created multiple CodeMirror cells. OnBlur works fine, however if I click `run` button on the other cell, instead of firing run, it actually triggers onBlur and then I need to click mouse again to trigger run. Ideally both of these events should be fired when run button is clicked.

I have seen that the issue is with the order of precedence for these two events and one of the proposed solutions was to add `ref` attribute to code mirror like this `ref = {cell => this.cell = cell}` and then in the other handler which is related to run button do `this.cell.focus()` or in some similar way.

Unfortunately I am not even able to access `ref` attribute for CodeMirror2 so I can't test it. I will paste both of these components and any suggestion is appreciated.

To summarize: The issue is that onBlur shadows onClick, so run button needs to be clicked twice. I want to be able to click run button and that both `onBlur` and `handleRunClick` fire.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Controlled as CodeMirror } from "react-codemirror2";
import CellResults from "./CellResults";
import CellToolbar from "../Shared/CellToolbar";
import AddCellButton from "../Shared/AddCellButton";
import "codemirror/lib/codemirror.css";
import "codemirror/theme/darcula.css";
import "codemirror/mode/javascript/javascript.js";
import "codemirror/mode/ruby/ruby.js";
import "codemirror/mode/python/python.js";

class CodeCell extends Component {
  state = {
    code: this.props.cell.code
  };

  handleChange = value => {
    this.setState({ code: value });
  };

  handleBlur = () => {
    this.props.onUpdateCodeState(this.state.code, this.props.cellIndex);

    if (this.props.language === "Markdown") {
      this.props.toggleRender(this.props.cellIndex);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const cell = this.props.cell;
    const cellOptions = {
      mode: cell.type.toLowerCase(),
      theme: "darcula",
      lineNumbers: true,
      showCursorWhenSelecting: true
    };

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="add-cell-container">
          <AddCellButton
            className="add-cell-btn"
            onClick={this.props.onAddClick}
            cellIndex={this.props.cellIndex}
          />
        </div>
        <CellToolbar
          cellIndex={this.props.cellIndex}
          onDeleteClick={this.props.onDeleteClick}
          language={cell.type}
          onLanguageChange={this.props.onLanguageChange}
          rendered={cell.rendered}
          onRunClick={this.props.onRunClick}
        />
        <CodeMirror
          value={this.state.code}
          options={cellOptions}
          onBeforeChange={(editor, data, value) => {
            this.handleChange(value);
          }}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
        />
        {cell.type !== "Markdown" ? (
          <CellResults language={cell.type} results={cell.results} />
        ) : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CodeCell;
```

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

class RunCellButton extends React.Component {
  handleRunClick = () => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.cellIndex);
  };
  render () {
    return (
      <Button
        className="run-button"
        onClick={this.handleRunClick}
        variant="secondary"
        size="sm"
      >
        <span>&#9658;</span>
      </Button>
    );
  }



};

export default RunCellButton;
```

Below is the similar problem with Adding Cell. When I trigger `click` event it fires, the state of `show` is changed to `true` but if I log it on line `36` it is still `false`. I am triggering click event from a different component, again due to this obBlue shadowing everything else so every button needs to be clicked twice.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SplitButton from "react-bootstrap/SplitButton";
import * as constants from "../../Constants/constants";
import DropdownButton from "react-bootstrap/DropdownButton";
import Dropdown from "react-bootstrap/Dropdown";

class AddCellButton extends Component {
  state = {
    show: false
  }
  handleSelectCellType = language => {
    this.props.onClick(this.props.cellIndex, language);
  };

  handleToggle = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        show: !prevState["show"]
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const dropDownItems = constants.LANGUAGES.map(language => {
      return (
        <Dropdown.Item
          as="button"
          value={language}
          key={language}
          eventKey={language}
        >
          {language}
        </Dropdown.Item>
      );
    });
    console.log("state of show " + this.state.show)
    return (
      <DropdownButton
        show={this.state.show}
        onToggle={this.handleToggle}
        className="add-cell-btn"
        variant="secondary"
        id="dropdown-basic-button"
        title={<span>&#43;</span>}
        size="sm"
        onSelect={this.handleSelectCellType}
      >
        {dropDownItems}
      </DropdownButton>
    );
  }
}

export default AddCellButton;
```

Comment: Related to the question above, I have the same issues when I click other buttons, for example, when I want to click that button that creates a dropdown to insert new cell. I have tried doing `e.relatedTarget.dropdown()` if the type of the element is button but that doesn't do the trick as it says that `dropdown()` is not a function.

Dropdown is implemented using bootstrap `DropdownButton`.

Comment: One of the reasons why I can't change the state of dropdown button show attribute to be `true` might be due to the fact that when `onUpdateCodeState` is called in `handleBlur` and I try to setState there in callback, it says that react can't perform state updates in unmounted component. So, `onUpdateCodeState` unmounts the component, not sure how to handle that though.